# How to debug a JUnit test class for RESTful Web Services in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, rest, debugging, intellij-idea, junit

I am just started to write JUnit test cases.Now I am writing a test method to test RESTful web service in java  using the IntelliJ IDEA. My directory structure as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Po9R.png).

I am calling the web service from my test case as:

```
Response response = target.path("groups").path("registergroup").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(stringEmp.toString()));
String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

I have added the multiple breakpoint in this test method and source classes.

Is it possible to jump Webservice classes from above request point?

If possible then how can I do that?

I am using the embedded jetty server to test which is also running from this module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing REST services using JUnit only is in my opinion not worth the effort, because you usually have to mock a lot of the REST library internals in order to make it work, and it's very hard to test some of the service behavior anyway (e.g. what happens when the client specifies the wrong `Content-Type` or `Accept` headers).

Assuming you are using Jersey, you have two options :

- use [JerseyTest](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)
- use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/blog/tags/rest/)

My personal preference goes to Arquillian because (among other things) the resulting tests are completely independent from what is being tested (i.e. you can change the implementation of the service *and* the REST library without changing the tests).

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But is there  any debug option through which I can  step into service class by test class. Previously I have done that but now i am not able to do that also i am not able to find how it works.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. There is no direct call to the service in your test method, so you can't do that. If you have already tried putting a breakpoint in the service method and it doesn't work, then the only options you have are to mock the rest library or to use JerseyTest (or Arquillian, or any other equivalent technology).